# dplyr - mutate using function that uses other column data as argument?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list with 3 regression models, called `logregs`. My data has a column called `type` that only has integers 1, 2, and 3, which are used to decide which regression model from `logregs` should be used, and a column called `adstock` which is the only independent variable used in the regression models.

I'm trying to do something like:

```r
dataframe %>% mutate(probability = predict(logregs[[type]], type = "prediction", newdata = adstock) )
```

Sample data frame:

```r
structure(list(type = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), adstock = c(1.7984, 
1.7984, 2.7984, 6.7984, 6.5968, 4.992)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

(unfortunately, the `logregs` models are too large to dput here)

How is this achievable using dplyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need to take some more care on subsetting `logregs`, and use `data.frame` on your `newdata=`.

I'll generate a quick set of models based on `mtcars`.

```r
library(dplyr)
models <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl = as.character(cyl)) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(mdl = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .x))) %>%
  arrange(cyl) %>%
  select(cyl, mdl) %>%
  deframe()
models
# $`4`
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = .x)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         disp  
#     40.8720      -0.1351  
# $`6`
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = .x)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         disp  
#   19.081987     0.003605  
# $`8`
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = .x)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         disp  
#    22.03280     -0.01963
```

Note that they are indexed on the `character` of the number of cylinders, since otherwise numeric indexing can be confusing.

Let's modify the `mtcars$disp` a little and to use it again:

```r
set.seed(42)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(disp = disp + sample(20, size=n(), replace = TRUE) - 10) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  sample_n(2)
# # A tibble: 6 x 11
# # Groups:   cyl [3]
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
# 2  21.5     4 129.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1
# 3  21       6 169     110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 4  19.2     6 173.    123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# 5  18.7     8 363     175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
# 6  16.4     8 281.    180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
```

The `[[` indexing on your `logregs` expects a single `type`, but you're actually passing a vector. Since my data here is still grouped, I can go with the first of the group variable (`cyl`) and do just a single call to `predict` per group:

```r
set.seed(42)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(disp = disp + sample(20, size=n(), replace = TRUE) - 10) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  sample_n(2) %>%
  mutate(mpg2 = predict(models[[as.character(cyl)[1]]], newdata = data.frame(disp)))
# # A tibble: 6 x 12
# # Groups:   cyl [3]
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  mpg2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2  30.6
# 2  21.5     4 129.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1  23.4
# 3  21       6 169     110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4  19.7
# 4  19.2     6 173.    123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4  19.7
# 5  18.7     8 363     175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2  14.9
# 6  16.4     8 281.    180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3  16.5
```

If you don't want to (or cannot) group, then you need to run one prediction per row. This is expensive in that it runs `predict` with a single `newdata=` argument, but ... it still works. To do this, we'll `map` it:

```r
library(purrr) # map* functions
set.seed(42)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(disp = disp + sample(20, size=n(), replace = TRUE) - 10) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  sample_n(2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(mpg2 = map2_dbl(cyl, disp, ~ predict(models[[as.character(.x)]], newdata = data.frame(disp=.y))))
# # A tibble: 6 x 12
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  mpg2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2  30.6
# 2  21.5     4 129.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1  23.4
# 3  21       6 169     110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4  19.7
# 4  19.2     6 173.    123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4  19.7
# 5  18.7     8 363     175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2  14.9
# 6  16.4     8 281.    180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3  16.5
```

Note that I had to name the column of `newdata=data.frame(disp=.y)`: when we did it before, `data.frame(disp)` names it the name of the import variable. In this case, `.y` is not known to the model, so we have to explicitly name it.

Comment: Btw, I just wanted to say thank you for the detailed and thorough answer. Not only it was exactly what I was looking for, but the steps detailed and the logic well documented. Thanks!